# Testing Logic with More than 1 && Operator?

Tags: matlab

If I have a function with 2 inputs, is there a way to test both its range other than nested if functions?

For example...

```
if input1 > 0 && input1 <10 && input2 > 0 && input2 <10
```

this doesn't work so I'm forced to write

```
if input1 > 0 && input1 <10 
    if input2 > 0 && input2 <10
    '%something
    end
end
```

Are there easier ways to test range of multiple inputs?

Comment: Why doesnt the first expression work ? there is no difference between the two expressions, unless you want to write some more code between the if statements

Comment: I think maybe you're saying that this "doesn't work" do to the [short circuiting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html#f0-39129) behavior of the `&&` operator. For example, if `input1 > 0` returns `false`, then none of the other conditions will be evaluated. It's not necessarily "easier, but the [`inputParser`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html) class is also available for such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to avoid nested if functions, but you can avoid repetition:

In JavaScript:

```
function test(argument1,argument2) {
    check = 0;
    for (i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        if (arguments[i] > 0 && (arguments[i] < 10)) {
            check++;
            if (check === arguments.length) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
test(1,2);
```

Comment: This is like proving 1=1 through integration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Matlab:

`find((input1==1:20),1) & find((input2==50:100),1)`